# Django Rest Framework serializer returning nested records that should be filtered out on update

Tags: django, django-rest-framework

I override my FormSerializer's update method. It marks some nested field records as is_deprecated if necessary. However, the Api call returns all records, even though my get_queryset filters out everything is_deprecated. As far as I can tell, the get_queryset is being called to get the instance, which is then passed to the serializer. This instance does not contain any previously deprecated records.

After the update method completes, it looks like another query must be run that gets ALL of these nested records and serializes them.  This only occurs on updates. This may be occurring when serializer is saved in UpdateModelMixin.update() when self.perform_update() is called.

I get the correct records on a standard GET request. Any idea where this second query is being called and how to override it? Alternatively, I should be able to edit the serialized data in to_representation, but this would be inefficient and I'd like to understand what is going on here first.

View

```
class FormViewSet(LoginRequiredMixin, viewsets.ModelViewSet):
    serializer_class = FormSerializer
    queryset = Form.objects.all()

    def get_queryset(self):
        if 'pk' in self.kwargs:
            qs = Form.objects.filter(id=self.kwargs['pk'])
        else:
            qs = Form.objects.filter(id__in=name_dict.values()).order_by('name')
        queryset = FormSerializer.eager_loading(qs)
        return queryset
```

Serializer

```
class FormSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
  id = serializers.IntegerField(required=False, allow_null=True)
  fields = FieldSerializer(many=True)

  class Meta:
      model = Form
      fields = '__all__'

  @staticmethod
  def eager_loading(queryset):
      return queryset.prefetch_related(Prefetch('fields',queryset=Field.objects.filter(is_deprecated=False).order_by('field_order')))
```

Comment: Could you share your update method? If it is private, can you say what is your return variable on update method?

Comment: Just to clarify, a GET request is returning the correct results but a PUT request is not? You're just sending the PUT for one object right? If it's a PUT the object should always be returned

Comment: @kamilyrb my update variable returns the instance

Comment: @Programmingjoe That is correct. My get request returns the filtered results described in the eager loading method.  But the PUT returns ALL related records as if the filter were never applied.  I have verified the instance I return in my update method has the correctly filtered records.

Comment: @Alex I'm a bit confused because a PUT request should only return the record that was updated but you're saying it's returning a list of records?

Comment: Programmingjoe The list is the nested fields. It only returns 1 top level record

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you look at the update method for the modelviewset, you will see that it invalidates the `prefetch_related` data so your eager loading doesn't work.

```
def update(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
    partial = kwargs.pop('partial', False)
    instance = self.get_object()
    serializer = self.get_serializer(instance, data=request.data, partial=partial)
    serializer.is_valid(raise_exception=True)
    self.perform_update(serializer)

    if getattr(instance, '_prefetched_objects_cache', None):
        # If 'prefetch_related' has been applied to a queryset, we need to
        # forcibly invalidate the prefetch cache on the instance.
        instance._prefetched_objects_cache = {}

    return Response(serializer.data)
```

This is done because the prefetched data could become obsolete after the update. So you can override the update method and redo the prefetch after the update

Comment: This is exactly what's happening.  Thank you for explaining this!

Answer (score 1):

I think, this answer should be a comment, but have no enough reputation.

`get_queryset` method called before `update` method of serializer.

What I mean by that:

1. Call for `update` -> PUT for view
2. View calls `get_queryset` -> Now we have not updated `is_deprecated` yet
3. View finds object to update and calls `update` of serializer -> You make changes
4. View returns instance from `update` method of serializer

So your `fields` field is same as on 2 point. Doesn't eager_loading, prefetch works like that? I mean loaded once, and that's it.

So you need to somehow manage to update your prefetched `fields` field.

Comment: What is confusing is the prefetched fields are filtered correctly. The problem is that the API ends up reterning ALL associated FIELD records. Even ones that were set to is_deprecated in prior calls and were not in my initial prefetch.At some point it must be making a secondary call to fetch all these additional records that I don't want.